# Sticky footer using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've created sticky footers in the past with jQuery through advice found here:

http://josephfitzsimmons.com/simple-sticky-footer-using-jquery/

How can i recreate the code below in my Controller:

```
var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
var vwptHeight = $(window).height();
if (vwptHeight > bodyHeight) {
    $("footer#colophon").css("position","absolute").css("bottom",0);
}
```

I've attempted to swap the first line with:

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $document) {

    var body = angular.element(document).find('body');
    console.log(body[0].offsetWidth);
```

And this returns a value, however how do i calculate the 'window' ??

Comment: This isn't something you should be doing in your controller, and why even use javascript for it?  See [this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/luhutedumo/2/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Is there any reason to use JavaScript to implement something that can be easily achieved in pure CSS? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: A sticky footer has no relation whatsoever with jQuery or Angular or anything else in JS. It's just pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you must use pure CSS to do a sticky footer. However the 'window' object is accessible by the service $window
See: `https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window`